# ¿Por qué no me instancia el FPDF?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, web

Hola amigos soy nuevo en este mundo apenas llevo un par de meses en esto... El problema que es que yo tengo que generar un pdf con datos de un formulario enviados por ajax, estoy usando la libreria FPDF y el require lo hace y todo pero a la hora de crear la instancia

$pdf = new FPDF();

Me genera error y no establece la conexión de ajax
Este es el boton para generar el PDF en jQuery

```
    //Evento de click en el boton para imprimir 
$("#imprimirBoton").on('click', function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: '../clases/fpdf/tutorial/tuto1.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("No se estableció conexión");
        }
   });
});
/* ************  */
```

Y aquí está el código en php haciendo un ejemplo basico pero me da error

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Aiudaaa por favooor no sé si tenga que hacer algo con la terminal o algo

Gracias al que me responda

Comment: Siempre es mas efectivo si desde el inicio agregas cual es el error que obtienes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: La respuesta de esto es debido a que el servidor no soportaba mbstring y hay que modificar el archivo .ini para que se pueda instanciar

Answer (score 0):

En el:

```
error: function(){
        alert("No se estableció conexión");
    }
```

Cambialo por el:

```
error: function(response){
        alert(response.responseText);

    }
```

y comenta el error que te esta lanzando AJAX, ya que por lo que veo parece ser un error con la URL hacia donde estas enviando las variables POST

Comment: No me había percatado de la fecha de publicación, de todas maneras parece mas un error de URL, espero pueda servir!